# prove - if a tends to L then Ma tends to ML

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is such that $a_n \rightarrow L$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Prove that for any $M>0, M \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $Ma_n \rightarrow ML$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  We will be better able to answer it if you share the context, where it comes from.  If this is homework, please label it as such.  Also, it would be helpful for you to share anything you've tried so far, as @Alvaro points out.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\overline{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{M},\forall n\geq\overline{n}$, because by hypothesys $a_n$ converges to $L$. Now, for every $n\geq\overline{n}$, you'll get

$$|Ma_n -ML|=M|a_n-L|\leq M\frac{\epsilon}{M}=\epsilon$$

This proves $Ma_n\rightarrow ML$

Answer (score -1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By the assumption, we can find an $N$ such that
$n\geqslant N \Rightarrow |a_{n} - L| < \varepsilon /M$.
then,
$n \ge N  \Rightarrow |Ma_{n}−ML|=M|a_{n} − L|< M*ϵ/M=ϵ$
which shows that if the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ tends to limit $L$ as $n\to\infty$ then, for any fixed number $M>0$, the sequence $\{Ma_{n}\}_{n=0}^\infty$ tends to the limit $ML$.

[image]

---

source: Course Introduction to Mathematical Thinking / Dr Keith Devlin

Comment: Did you read the answer posted 6 months ago?